# Unsupported compression jpeg sof type 0xc7

Tags: jpeg, irfanview

I cannot open jpeg. Irfan show me this message: Unsupported JPEG process/compression: SOF type 0xc7. Any ideas how to open? Maybe some program to open that file?

link to the image file: http://www.filedropper.com/zwojtczak6

Answer (score -1):

That particular SOF type indicates an uncompressed JPEG file, which is extremely rare - I don't know of any general purpose software that might be able to open it.  A utility from the camera's manufacturer, for your specific camera, would be about the only hope of converting it to a standard format.

Another possibility is that the file is simply corrupted, in which case recovery is unlikely (as there is probably more corruption than just that one byte).